# Do we have any statistical measures / estimates of how much mass, as a fraction of the total, is contained in black holes?

Tags: black-holes, mass, observable-universe

Do we have any measures or estimates (from the visible universe or perhaps avg. per galaxy) of how much mass is contained in black holes vs everything else?

Comment: Off hand, I would expect it is low. The centers of galaxies may have black holes of millions or billions of solar masses. A galaxy may contain trillions of stars. As far as I know, the fraction of stars that has collapsed into individual black holes is not high, though I don't know what it is.

Comment: Good point - Thanks @mmesser314.

Comment: There are estimates from gravitational lensing, eg.  [Limits on stellar-mass compact objects as dark matter from gravitational lensing of type Ia supernovae](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.02240) although I don't see where they give a mass fraction.